# Python igraph does not show vertex and edge labels in iPython notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, igraph, anaconda, graph-visualization

I am trying to visualize a simple network with both vertex and edge labels using igraph Python. I am using OS X 10.2.2, Python 2.7.9 Anaconda, igraph 0.7.1, iPython 3.0. When I build the code with a Python interpreter it shows the plot correctly. However, when I tried to do the same with iPython notebook, it does not show the vertex and edge labels. Any idea how can I fix it? This is my code.

```
import igraph

G = igraph.Graph(directed = True)

G.add_vertices(n = 8)
G.vs['name'] = range(8)
G.vs['label'] = range(8)
print G.vs['label']

G.add_edges([(0,1),(0,2),(1,3),(2,3),(3,4),(4,3),(5,4),(6,4),(7,5),(7,6)])
G.es['weight'] = [2,4,3,2,1,1,2,4,3,2]
G.es["name"] = range(10)
G.es["label"] = range(10)

G.summary()

igraph.plot(G, bbox = (300,300), vertex_label_color = 'black', 
        vertex_label_size = 10, vertex_size = 20, vertex_color = 'white',
                                      edge_width = [edge for edge in G.es['weight']])
```

Comment: You need to make sure that you have version 0.7 of igraph.

Comment: I have the 0.7.1 version.